# org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column count does not match when it does

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, h2

I've set up the following POJO:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "SpreadsheetRequest")
public class SpreadsheetRequest {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false, unique = true)
    @Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private Integer id;

    private String spreadsheetId;
    private String name;
    private String range;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public SpreadsheetRequest() {
        setSpreadsheetId(null);
        setName(null);
        setRange(null);
    }
}
```

And configured my environment as follows:

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=embedded
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files=classpath://resources/import.sql
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

`import.sql` looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO SPREADSHEET_REQUEST VALUES ('DYsErzRPCLEoYYzQkemEAeerYiQ3Usyn','Test','Sheet1!A1:A12');
```

I keep getting the following error on load:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column count does not match; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO SPREADSHEET_REQUEST VALUES ('DYsErzRPCLEoYYzQkemEAeerYiQ3Usyn','Test','Sheet1!A1:A12') [21002-197]
```

What's causing it?

Comment: I see you have this @Table(name = "SpreadsheetRequest") then why the generated sql has insert into spreadsheet_request?

Comment: Spring by default uses org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.SpringNamingStrategy which transforms camel case names into upper case names with an underscore

Comment: You should also specify the column list, that enforce which columns you want to use, and their order. It will decouple/protect you from schema changes (adding columns or reordering, or dropping + adding columns)

Comment: Add this annotation @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) and see your problem will go away

Comment: @MarkRotteveel tried this and got the following error: `Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "INSERT INTO SPREADSHEET_REQUEST (SPREADSHEET_ID, NAME, RANGE) VALUES[*]"; expected "("; SQL statement: INSERT INTO SPREADSHEET_REQUEST (SPREADSHEET_ID, NAME, RANGE) VALUES [42001-197]`

Comment: @shakeelosmani sadly does not work changed `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` to `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)`
 to

Comment: That looks like you forgot the values clause, as the error suggests the statement you executed was only `"INSERT INTO SPREADSHEET_REQUEST (SPREADSHEET_ID, NAME, RANGE) VALUES"` and not `"INSERT INTO SPREADSHEET_REQUEST (SPREADSHEET_ID, NAME, RANGE) VALUES ('DYsErzRPCLEoYYzQkemEAeerYiQ3Usyn','Test','Sheet1!A1:A12')"`

Comment: @MarkRotteveel my sql looks like this: `INSERT INTO SPREADSHEET_REQUEST (SPREADSHEET_ID, NAME, RANGE) VALUES ('DYsErzRPCLEoYYzQkemEAeerYiQ3Usyn','Test','Sheet1!A1:A12');`

Comment: The error message seems to disagree with you, are you sure you didn't accidentally truncate it or that linebreaks somewhere influence how the query is read from file?

Comment: Check this code https://github.com/shakeelosmani/springcoffeeshop/blob/master/src/main/java/com/shakeel/model/Customer.java

This is working code.

Comment: Sorry just had to rerun... the error I get is now: `Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: NULL not allowed for column "ID"; SQL statement:`

Comment: And that error suggest the id column is not created as an identity column (or alternative method of generating an id for the primary key, eg a trigger).

Comment: Where is the DDL of that table? Basic info. That should be step 1 in debugging.

Comment: @methuselah The DDL is where your problem is ... if you use `IDENTITY` strategy then your JPA provider should specify the ID column as `IDENTITY` (for H2, and so it would not be needed on an INSERT)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause is

> Column count does not match

You attept to insert 3 columns while your entity (so the table in db as well) has 4 columns. Include `id` to the query:

```
INSERT INTO SPREADSHEET_REQUEST VALUES (1, 'DYsErzRPCLEoYYzQkemEAeerYiQ3Usyn','Test','Sheet1!A1:A12');
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this and it works. But why isn't the id autogenerated?

Comment: @methuselah Your insert statement doesn't specify a column list, so the database expects values for **all** columns.

Comment: I get the following error: `Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "INSERT INTO SPREADSHEET_REQUEST (SPREADSHEET_ID, NAME, RANGE) VALUES[*]"; expected "("; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO SPREADSHEET_REQUEST (SPREADSHEET_ID, NAME, RANGE) VALUES [42001-197]`

Comment: My SQL looks like this: `INSERT INTO SPREADSHEET_REQUEST (SPREADSHEET_ID, NAME, RANGE) VALUES ('DYsErzRPCLEoYYzQkemEAeerYiQ3Usyn','Test','Sheet1!A1:A12');`

Comment: Can confirm Hibernate is creating table: `Hibernate: create table spreadsheet_request (id integer not null, name varchar(255), range varchar(255), spreadsheet_id varchar(255), primary key (id))`

Comment: @methuselah The "id" isnt generated because the table is NOT created with "id" as IDENTITY type. So whatever created it, did it wrong.